# How to estimate the MLE for a probit panel data model in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, panel-data, probit

Can you recommend a good package in R to calculate the MLE for a simple panel data probit model?

I would like to use GHK simulator to do it. But What I found is not for panel data in R.

Comment: Lme4::glmer might be the ticket.